# Property 'ensure' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying webpack 2 code splitting.

According to this doc: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/

the following code should include some.css into a new chunk named 'something'

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
    require('some.css');
}, 'something');
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(4,9): error TS2339: Property 'ensure' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.
```

Any idea about how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 6):

The way I solved this was by creating my own interface - `WebpackRequire` - which extends `NodeRequire` with `ensure`<sup>1</sup>.

```
interface WebpackRequire extends NodeRequire {
  ensure(
    dependencies: string[],
    callback: (require: WebpackRequire) => void,
    errorCallback?: (error: Error) => void,
    chunkName?: string
  ): void;
};
```

If you've only got a single instance of `require.ensure`, you can then type cast it to a `WebpackRequire` using `(require as WebpackRequire).ensure`, but since I used it multiple times in a module, I created local `require` at the top scope of the module, type cast as `WebpackRequire`, like this:

```
const require: WebpackRequire = (window as any).require;
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>I got the types of `ensure` from the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#require-ensure-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I required a javascript document which then did the require.  Not exactly the nicest solution, but it did work